# Как обработать исключение в конструкторе?

Tags: java

Есть следующий клас:

```
public class Knowledge {
    int level;
    public Knowledge(int level) {
        if (0 < level && level < 11){
            this.level = level;
        } else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("level is out of range [1,10]: " + level);
        }
    }
}
```

Как правильно обработать исключение которое выкинет этот конструктор в том месте, где я буду его ловить в блоке `catch`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это будет выглядеть к примеру так:

```
try {
    final Knowledge knowledge = new Knowledge(0);
} catch(final IllegalArgumentException e) {
    System.out.println(e.getMessage()); // level is out of range [1,10]: 0
}
```